# Pandas pd.read_csv does not work for simple sep=';'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Im trying to make a program that can read multiple csv file at the same time and add a sertain value together within a sertain time frame, but the csv files are getting generated with the seperator ;

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=";", index_col=0)

# Find the colsest column to the target column
closest_column = find_closest_column(df, target_column)

if closest_column:
    # Assumin 'Recipe' and the closeset column are in the correct format, proceed with grouping
    # grouped_df = df.groupby("Recipe")[closest_column].sum().reset_index()
    print(f"\nFile: {file_path}, Closest Column: {closest_column}\n")
else:
    print(f"\nColumn similar to '{target_column}' not found in the DataFram for file: {file_path}\n")
```

do to the way the files have been made, i've changed on of them to have the seperator to be a comma, out of the two files it see the columns but only gets the value of the one that has the comma spearator

```
File: C:\Users\nw\Documents\Mini projects\CSV\test\656062f4cd3a83000200000a.csv, Closest Column: Total volume[m3],"0.1"


File: C:\Users\nw\Documents\Mini projects\CSV\test\99-Card.csv, Closest Column: Total volume[m�]
```

how could i get the semicolon to also get the value assosiated with the columns

i've looked up with the pandas documentation what could change the sep/delimiter could be set as, but it hasnt changed anything.

Comment: Pls post a sample to your data

Comment: Recipe;water
Batch no;99
Order no;3
Serial no;F1200 1406545
Company;Card
Purchaser;
Truck no;
Job designation;

Batch start;DT#2023-10-30-12:05:01
Batch end;DT#2023-10-30-12:07:57
Mixing time[s];12
Act. WCT;0.0
Set p. WCT;0.0
Total volume[m�];0.1

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue it was the quotation mark

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='";', engine='python', encoding="ANSI", index_col=0)
```

where it was sep=";" before which didn't make it work correctly and with it changed to sep='";' it works as it was meant to